# $f(x,x)\geq f(y,x)$ for all $(x,y)\in[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Let $f:[0,1]^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that for all $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$ one has $f(x,x)\geq f(y,x)$.

Is there anything special one can say about such a function (even assuming further hypothesis such as differentiability)? I guess not much but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: That is has a maximum on $\{(x,x) : x\in [0,1]\}$, for example. Is there something specific that you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

For each $0\le y\le1$ define the function $g_y(x)=f(x,y)$ on $[0,1]$

Assuming the derivatives exist, then you have $$\frac {dg_y}{dx}|_{x=y}=0$$ and $$\frac {d^2g_y}{dx^2}|_{x=y}<0$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming differentiability, you can say $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_{(t,t)} = 0,$ $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}|_{(t,t)} \le 0,$ for $0<t<1$.